# SQL query with three level categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

This problem has puzzled me a while and I hope there are some wiz that could help solve this problem. I have a product table with three level of categories (three tables). I'm trying to list all products that is connected to the last level(third level) of the categories. When running the query below *ALL* products in the product table is listed.

Here is the SQL query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Product_Category 
    ON Product.ProductCategoryID = Product_Category.ProductCategoryID
INNER JOIN Product_Sub_Category 
    ON Product_Category.ProductCategoryID = Product_Sub_Category.ProductCategoryID
INNER JOIN Product_Sub_Sub_Category 
    ON Product_Sub_Category.ProductSubCategoryID = Product_Sub_Sub_Category.ProductSubCategoryID
WHERE Product_Sub_Sub_Category.ProductSubSCategoryID = request.querystring
```

Comment: Can you give an example? What you wrote looks like it might work, if I understand your question correctly. So I assume I must not understand it.

Comment: Perhaps all products have the sub sub category you are looking for.  If you have a small example, you can put it up on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: If you inner join it down selects to those things that match the criteria. Are you sure something isn't "connected" to that third level?

Comment: are `Product_Sub_Sub_Category.ProductSubCategoryID` and `Product_Sub_Sub_Category.ProductSubSCategoryID` actually different or is that a typo?

Comment: To Daniel E. no that is not a typo `ProductSubSCategoryID` is the unique ID in the third table.

Comment: I would suggest testing by adding a new product in a new `ProductSubSCategoryID` and try to select on that one, because the query looks like it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel E. Your suggestion helped me discover an error! When I registered a product in the product table all products where assigned the wrong categoryID. I feel very embarrassed but then again without any good input and suggestions it might be difficult to find even the most obvious errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on SubCategoryId on the second level and SubSubCategoryId on the third level

```
SELECT *
FROM
  Product
  INNER JOIN Product_Category ON (Product.ProductCategoryID = Product_Category.ProductCategoryID)
  INNER JOIN Product_Sub_Category ON (Product_Category.ProductSubCategoryID = Product_Sub_Category.ProductSubCategoryID)
  INNER JOIN Product_Sub_Sub_Category ON (Product_Sub_Category.ProductSubSubCategoryID = Product_Sub_Sub_Category.ProductSubSubCategoryID)
WHERE
  Product_Sub_Sub_Category.ProductSubSubCategoryID = (request.querystring)
```

Comment: There is no columns (based on the info OP has provided) called "ProductSubSubCategory" in the **Product_Sub_Sub_Category** Table. On what basis are you stating on answer?

Comment: This answer is completely ignorant of the column names the OP has provided and is wrong!!!